# map<T,T>::iterator as parameter type

Tags: c++, stl, parameters, iterator

I have a template class with a private map member

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(){}
private:
    std::map<T,T> myMap;
}
```

I would like to create a private method that accepts an iterator to the map

```
void MyFunction(std::map<T,T>::iterator &myIter){....}
```

However, this gets a compile error: identifier 'iterator'. I don't need to pass an abstract iterator since MyFunction knows that it is a map iterator (and will only be used as a interator for myMap) and will treat it as such (accessing and modifying myIter->second). Passing myIter->second to MyFunction is not enough since MyFunction will also need to be able to ++myIter;.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that `std::map<T,T>::iterator` is a type—it could be anything depending on what `std::map<T,T>` is. You must specify this explicitly with `typename std::map<T,T>::iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `typename`:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(){}
private:
    void MyFunction(typename std::map<T,T>::iterator &myIter){....}

    std::map<T,T> myMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add "typename" keyword before std::map<T,T>::iterator in parameters list.